# How to apply padding to the legend?

Tags: angular

How to apply padding to the legend in the component.ts.I tried to apply padding in the component.css but padding is not applied to the legend.Please help me how to solve this error. 
 I am using the plugin

```
<script 

    src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>



 public options:any = {
        Label: {
            display: true,
        },
        // legend: {position: 'bottom'},
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    };


     <div id="mychart" style="display: block;max-width:400px;margin:75px auto">
                <canvas baseChart
                [data]="doughnutChartData"
                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                [colors]="colors"
                [options]="options"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
            </div>
```

Comment: What module is providing the chart? Given CSS encapsulation in Angular, you probably need to add `/deep/ #mychart { ... }` to apply the styles to nested components.

Comment: what is the library you are using

Comment: @ jonrsharpe @ Sajeetharan i am using the plugin <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>